# Viewing the full output of an xarray DataArray in plain text

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I am trying to view the full output of

```
print(MyDataArray)
```

instead of the shortened version which displays

```
array([[[[[0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
           0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
          [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
           0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
          [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
           0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
          ...,
          [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
           0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
          [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
           0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
          [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
           0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00]],
```

(this is a code snippet and not the full output i get)
basically i'm trying to get rid of the `...`.
I would like to see this output just as plain text, or written to a text file. I would like to maintain the current formatting.

I have already tried a number of things

1. increasing `display_max_rows` to a very large number (this is an option of xarray)
2. writing to an npz file, this resulted in a file I could only open in python, not allowing me to see it in plain text
3. exporting it to a normal python file (instead of jupyter notebook) and trying to print it from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just solved my own question, I'm posting this information if somebody also encounters this problem. My solution is a workaround

```
new_numpy_ndarray = existing_xarray_DataArray.to_numpy()
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.Inf)
print(new_numpy_array)
```

this allows you to then view your array in full.
Thank you to whoever recommended

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.Inf)
```

this gave me the idea to convert my array to numpy

Comment: Great job! Make sure to accept your answer and mark this question as closed.